# How to use android ndk to compile glib 2.66 with meson?

Tags: android-ndk, glib, meson-build

Enviroment:

Compiler: android-ndk-r21b, api 24

Ubuntu 20.04

Glib 2.66

I have built iconv, and have built glib 2.56 with make successfully, now i try to build glib 2.66 with meson,  i build i run this script:

```
OUTDIR=$HOME/work/ndk/builddir/out
CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc CFLAGS="-L$OUTDIR/lib -I$OUTDIR/include" LDFLAGS="-L$OUTDIR/lib" LIBS="-liconv" CXXFLAGS="-L$OUTDIR/lib" meson release/ \
    --cross-file cross_file.txt \
    --prefix=$OUTDIR \
```

but compile error:

```
Header <iconv.h> has symbol "iconv_open" : YES 

meson.build:1930:4: ERROR: C shared or static library 'iconv' not found

A full log can be found at /home/git/work/ndk/builddir/glib-2.66.4/reconfigure/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
```

cross_file.txt:

```
[host_machine]
system = 'android'
cpu_family = 'arm'
cpu = 'arm'
endian = 'little'

[constants]
android_ndk = '/home/git/work/ndk/toolchain/bin/'
toolchain = '/home/git/work/ndk/toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-'
outdir = '/home/git/work/ndk/builddir/out/'

[binaries]
c = android_ndk + 'arm-linux-androideabi-gcc'
cpp = android_ndk +  'arm-linux-androideabi-g++'
ar = android_ndk + 'arm-linux-androideabi-ar'
ld = android_ndk + 'arm-linux-androideabi-ld'
c_ld = android_ndk + 'arm-linux-androideabi-ld'
objcopy = android_ndk + 'arm-linux-androideabi-objcopy'
strip = android_ndk + 'arm-linux-androideabi-strip'
pkgconfig = '/usr/bin/pkg-config'

[built-in options]
c_std = 'c11'
libdir = '/home/git/work/ndk/builddir/out/lib'
prefix = '/home/git/work/ndk/builddir/out/'
c_args = ['-L/home/git/work/ndk/builddir/out/lib', '-I/home/git/work/ndk/builddir/out/include']
cpp_args = ['-L/home/git/work/ndk/builddir/out/lib', '-I/home/git/work/ndk/builddir/out/include']
c_link_args = ['-I/home/git/work/ndk/builddir/out/include', '-L/home/git/work/ndk/builddir/out/lib']
pkg_config_path = '/home/git/work/ndk/builddir/out/lib/pkgconfig'
```

Comment: This is probably related:
https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/6114

Comment: I've solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got it. I shouldn't set the `c_ld` variable. And there is a bug in meson scripts of gio, so i must apt remove libelf-dev on ubuntu(or modify gio/meson.build).

Visit my github to get config file:

https://github.com/edaplayer/android-ndk-harfbuzz/blob/main/glib-2.66.4/build_glib_meson.sh

https://github.com/edaplayer/android-ndk-harfbuzz/blob/main/glib-2.66.4/cross_file.txt